# Passing value of Vendor Ref in detail transactions of Check and Payment to Bill and Adjusment for 'Bill' transaction type in Acumatica ERP

Tags: c#, customization, acumatica, erp

I have already create a document using type = 'check' in screen Checks and Payments (AP302000) of Acumatica ERP and released it. Please refer to this screenshot below.

[image]

and then I will set off this payment using bill. Please refer to this screenshot below.

[image]

I want to pass Vendor Ref of detail transaction in Checks and Payments's screen to a new additional field in Applications tab Menu of Bill and Adjustments screen when I create bill using the same vendor.

Should I create new additional field ? and then should I create APPaymentEntryExtension in Release action to passing this Vendor Ref of APAdjust to new additional field in Application Tab Menu of Bill's screen ?
Or maybe is there another way without create new additional field ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's enough to declare custom unbound field for the APAdjust DAC and populate it inside RowSelecting (for records with **0 Amount Paid**) and RowInserting (for records with **Amount Paid greater then 0**) handlers within the APInvoiceEntry BLC extension:

```
public class APAdjustExt : PXCacheExtension<APAdjust>
{
    public abstract class invoiceNbr : IBqlField
    { }

    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor Ref.")]
    public string InvoiceNbr { get; set; }
}

public class APInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    protected void APAdjust_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        APAdjust row = e.Row as APAdjust;
        if (row == null) return;

        using (var connScope = new PXConnectionScope())
        {
            row.GetExtension<APAdjustExt>().InvoiceNbr = GetInvoiceNbr(row);
        }
    }

    protected void APAdjust_RowInserting(PXCache sender, PXRowInsertingEventArgs e)
    {
        APAdjust row = e.Row as APAdjust;
        if (row != null)
        {
            row.GetExtension<APAdjustExt>().InvoiceNbr = GetInvoiceNbr(row);
        }
    }

    private string GetInvoiceNbr(APAdjust adjustment)
    {
        string invoiceNbr = null;

        var doc = (APInvoice)PXSelect<APInvoice,
            Where<APInvoice.docType, Equal<Required<APInvoice.docType>>,
                And<APInvoice.refNbr, Equal<Required<APInvoice.refNbr>>>>>
            .Select(Base, adjustment.AdjgDocType, adjustment.AdjgRefNbr);
        if (doc != null)
        {
            invoiceNbr = doc.InvoiceNbr;
        }

        return invoiceNbr;
    }
}
```